# Is this a proper use of the asynchronous cababilities of the Socket class?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

```
/// <summary></summary>
private Byte[] _ReceiveBytes(Int32 size)
{
    MemoryStream memory = null;  
    SocketAsyncEventArgs args = null;
    EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs> completed = null;
    Exception exception = null;
    Int32 last_update = Environment.TickCount;
    Boolean finished = false;
    Int32 count = 0;
    Int32 received = 0;

    completed = new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>((s, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            count = e.BytesTransferred;
            last_update = (count > 0 ? Environment.TickCount : last_update);
            memory.Write(e.Buffer, 0, count);
            received += count;
            finished = (received == size);
            if (!finished)
            {
                count = Math.Min(_ChunkSize, size - received);
                args.SetBuffer(new Byte[count], 0, count);
                if (!_Socket.ReceiveAsync(e))
                {
                    completed(s, e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }
    });

    using (memory = new MemoryStream())
    using (args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs())
    {
        count = Math.Min(_ChunkSize, size - received);
        args.SetBuffer(new Byte[count], 0, count);
        args.Completed += completed;

        if (!_Socket.ReceiveAsync(args))
        {
            completed(_Socket, args);
        }

        while (!finished)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(_SleepTimeSpan);
            if (exception != null)
            {
                throw new Exception(_ReceiveExceptionMessage, exception);
            }
            else if (!finished && Environment.TickCount - last_update > _ReceiveTimeout)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException(_TimeoutExceptionMessage);
            }
        }

        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: The possibility of posting code for review was discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405009/so-community-code-reviews . Seeing it happen for real, I must say I doubt you'll get many answers. At least your co-workers would be paid to review code. The idea with the Q/A format is that several persons will have the same question and benefit from well-crafted answers. With reviews, not so much...

Comment: I suspected as much. I still want to keep it up for a while in case any kind souls are interested.

Comment: You should single out issues which you think are of concern and formulate a generic question, that way we can answer it more generically and the answer maybe used over and over with whoever runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are problems.  "finished" needs to be volatile but can't be, use MRE. Your timeout code can crash on a OverflowException.  You're translating exceptions.

But the approach makes no sense, there's no point in waiting for an async operation to complete.  Use Socket.ReceiveTimeout to get the timeout exception.

Comment: I don't think finished needs to be volatile in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422/is-a-bool-read-write-atomic-in-c