# How can I make sure my task is aware of a flag set on the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, synchronization, task

I'm using the Unity game engine to do some networking, and I want to use the built-in language features rather than rely on a third-party asset or Unity API. I've come up with this component, which attaches to a GameObject. When the game object is enabled, it should send UDP packets to a specified destination.

That part works. The trouble I'm having is with this `sending` flag:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UdpTest
{
    public class DummySender : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string destinationAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        public int port = 55555;

        UdpClient client;
        bool sending;
        IPEndPoint endpoint;

        private void Awake()
        {
            client = new UdpClient();
            try
            {
                endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(destinationAddress), port);
                client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 5000);
                client.Connect(endpoint);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't set up dummy sender: " + e.Message, gameObject);
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            sending = true;
            new Task(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.Log("Ready to send");
                    while (sending)
                    {
                        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + "\n");
                        client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Dummy send failed: " + e.Message);
                }
            }).Start();
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            sending = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I can't make it stop, once the task with the loop is running.

My plan was to make it stop when the component is disabled, by setting the `sending` flag to false. I realize that setting the flag to false happens on a different thread. My expectation was that, yes, the loop may run a few more times between the `sending` flag getting set to false and the task accessing its value, but that is fine for my purposes.

**However,** what is actually happening is that the task doesn't seem to ever become aware that the value of `sending` has changed. It remains `true`, The loop runs indefinitely, and my receiver doesn't stop receiving packets until I kill the program.

Why is this? I'm a bit new to low-level tasks/threading, but I understand that there's no guarantee that the worker task would be aware of the change immediately. I would have expected it to update eventually. But in my case, although I can verify that the `sending` flag has been set to false on the main thread, the loop in the task never stops.

If I had to guess, this seems like the same kind of mistake as you get when you copy a value and change the original (i.e. a by reference/by value mistake). Does the task actually have a copy of `sending` and not a reference to the class instance field? Or am I missing something else?

I know there are other strategies to achieve UDP communications, such as using the `Async` variants but, for the sake of learning, I would like to know what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it without changing tack completely.

Comment: Would be really nice if someone would point out why this question is anti-valuable as well, if you are going to vote it down, as I am apparently clueless on that as well.

Comment: Try declaring the `sending` variable as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Like this: `volatile bool sending;`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411961/c-sharp-and-thread-safety-of-a-bool, adding volatile keyword doesn't guarantee the field to be thread-safe.

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan this case has less to do with thread-safety, and more to do with visibility. One thread is not seeing a change made to a variable by another thread. The topic of visibility is extremely obscure and complex, and the details are hairy and sometimes scary. Here are two related questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166019/c-sharp-bool-is-atomic-why-is-volatile-valid), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516863/does-interlocked-provide-visibility-in-all-threads).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's exactly what I meant by thread-safe. Here is the definition of "thread-safe" - Thread-safe code only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that ensures that all threads behave properly and fulfill their design specifications without unintended interaction.

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan for me "thread-safety" is about shared state not being corrupted when manipulated by multiple threads. In this particular case declaring the field as `volatile` seems good enough, since this field is queried continuously in a loop. The `CancellationTokenSource` class uses `volatile` fields too [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs.html), to ensure visibility. My advice would be to use `lock` instead of `volatile`, because locking is much easier to reason about, compared to the tricky `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I m glad that u looked up the code to see that it's marked volatile indeed, but pls go ahead and see how .Cancel () works. It uses Interlocked class.

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan yes, `Cancel` is using `Interlocked` to ensure that only one thread will do the cancellation work. But `IsCancellationRequested` is not using `Interlocked`, and just relies on the volatility of the `m_state` field to ensure visibility. So in OP's case if the `OnDisable` method had to do more work that just changing the `sending` field to `false`, adding the `volatile` keyword would not be enough to ensure that this extra work would be done only once.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue with the same task. Fixed it using CancellationTokenSource. Here is how:

```
 var source = new CancellationTokenSource ();
 Task.Factory.StartNew ( obj => YourMethod ( (CancellationToken) obj ), source.Token, source.Token );

public void YourMethod ( CancellationToken token )
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        ;// insert ur code
}
```

And to cancel it, store somewhere globally that source variable, then when want to cancel call:

```
source.Cancel ();
```

Also u had there this line:

```
client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 5000);
```

which is completely useless, since UDP by definition is a contactless protocol, so .Connect and .Send don't block the thread. All .Connect does is to set the default IPEndPoint when calling .Send without providing the target IPEndPoint

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did come across the cancellation token pattern also - but for the sake of edification I would like to know what is preventing the change in this boolean flag from being picked up inside the Task - any idea about that?

Comment: Here is an excellent answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411961/c-sharp-and-thread-safety-of-a-bool. Basically, to be able to retrieve data from another thread, you have to duplicate it using the right context. CancellationToken is simply a storage of the reference to the CancellationTokenSource, which takes care of everything.

Comment: @Joseph R u satisfied with answer? Pls mark it as answered.

Comment: I do appreciate this alternative approach, it is helpful. But please note that the question is "what is wrong" - there has been some useful ifno in the comments that you saw as well, but nobody has put that forward as part of an answer.