# How to stop a loop created in another thread

Tags: c#

I made a image recorder in a loop below, but I don't understand how I can stop recording. Here's my code

```
void Capture()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Bitmap bm= new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;
        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
}

private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Capture);
    t.Start();
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: How do i save the recording?

Answer (score 3):

Because of your loop you have a very simple ways: set a flag as a request to stop:

```
private volatile bool reqToStopRec = false;

void Capture()
{
    while (!reqToStopRec)
    {
        Bitmap bm= new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;
        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
    reqToStopRec = false;
}

private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Capture);
    t.Start();
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reqToStopRec = true;
}
```

[In C# `bool` writes and reads are atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422/is-a-bool-read-write-atomic-in-c-sharp) so all you need is `volatile`.

Comment: how do u save the recording

Comment: @JohnDoe We have a policy on SO of one question per post.

Comment: oh um could u comment it?