# when to use a Singleton?

Tags: .net, oop, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

I want to know what is the real time scenario when one should use singleton design pattern.

Comment: Please search before posting.  This question has been asked and answered thoroughly many times.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an object that's expensive to create, and there is logical that only one instance should exist. It will come to you :)