# What are some good uses of the Singleton pattern? Is it ever acceptable?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

I've read that singletons are bad. For instance, it makes the code hard to test. Are there any acceptable uses of singletons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you want one and only one connection to a database.  Making your connector a singleton ensures that you will not spin up multiple connections.