# Problem with singleton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make a singleton containing information "title, comments, Two picture" and it saves all the information in an array
I want to do is these objects in my application I use it All The Time

```
@interface CarteManager : NSObject {


NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *carteMan; 

+(CarteManager*)sharedInstance;

-(void)ajouttitre:(NSString*)txt; 
-(void)ajoutcom:(NSString*)com; 
-(void)ajoutimage1:(UIImage*)img; 
-(void)ajoutimage2:(UIImage*)img; 


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a Singleton you will need a static instance.

```
@implementation CarteManager

static CarteManager *_carteManager = nil;

+(CarteManager*)sharedInstance {
   if (!_carteManager) {
        _carteManager = [[CarteManager alloc] init];
    }

    return _carteManager;
}

// your other codes

@end
```

And before creating a Singleton, make sure that you really need a Singleton. Please pay special attention to [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your problem. If it's how to make the object a singleton, you can find several possible implementations in the question [What does your Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).