# Singleton pattern: different behavior of auto_ptr and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, static, linker, singleton, auto-ptr

While implementing a factory class I encountered a behavior of `std::auto_ptr` that I am not able to understand. I reduced the problem down to the following small program, so ... let's start.

Consider the following singleton class:

singleton.h

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H_
#define SINGLETON_H_

#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

class singleton {
public:
  static singleton* get() {
    std::cout << "singleton::get()" << std::endl;
    if ( !ptr_.get() ) {
      std::cout << &ptr_ << std::endl;
      ptr_.reset( new singleton  );
      std::cout << "CREATED" << std::endl;
    }
    return ptr_.get();
  }

  ~singleton(){
    std::cout << "DELETED" << std::endl;
  }
private:
  singleton() {}
  singleton(const singleton&){}

  static std::auto_ptr< singleton > ptr_;
  //static std::unique_ptr< singleton > ptr_;
};

#endif
```

singleton.cpp

```
#include<singleton.h>o
std::auto_ptr< singleton > singleton::ptr_(0);
//std::unique_ptr< singleton > singleton::ptr_;
```

Here the use of a smart pointer to manage the resource is mainly dictated by the need to avoid leaks at program exit. I use then this code in the following program:

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

int foo();

#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include<singleton.h>

namespace {
  singleton * dummy( singleton::get() );
}

int foo() {  
  singleton * pt = singleton::get();
  return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<a.h>

int main() {

  int a = foo();

  return 0;
}
```

Now the *funny* part. I compile the three sources separately:

```
$ g++  -I./ singleton.cpp -c 
$ g++  -I./ a.cpp -c 
$ g++  -I./ main.cpp -c
```

If I link them explicitly in this order:

```
$ g++ main.o singleton.o a.o
```

everything work as I expect, and I get the following to stdout:

```
singleton::get()
0x804a0d4
CREATED
singleton::get()
DELETED
```

If instead I link the sources using this order:

```
$ g++ a.o main.o singleton.o
```

I get this output:

```
singleton::get()
0x804a0dc
CREATED
singleton::get()
0x804a0dc
CREATED
DELETED
```

I tried different compiler brands (Intel and GNU) and versions and this behavior is consistent among them. Anyhow, I am not able to see code whose behavior depends on the order of linking.

Furthermore, if `auto_ptr` is substituted by `unique_ptr` the behavior is ALWAYS consistent with what I expect to be the correct one.

That brings me to the question: **Does anybody have a clue on what's going on here?**

Comment: what is your g++ version?

Comment: You probably want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order at which `dummy` and `std::auto_ptr< singleton > singleton::ptr_(0)` is constructed is unspecified.

For the `auto_ptr` case, if you construct `dummy` then `singleton::ptr_(0)`, the value created in the `dummy` call is erased by the constructor of `ptr_(0)`.

I would add tracking to the construction of `ptr_` via `ptr_(([](){ std::cout << "made ptr_\n"; }(),0));` or something like that.

The fact that it works with `unique_ptr` is coincidental, and possibly due to optimizations whereby `unique_ptr(0)` can figure out it is zeroed, as such does nothing (`static` data is zeroed before construction starts, so if the compiler could figure out that `unique_ptr(0)` just zeros the memory, it could legally skip the constructor, which means you no longer zero the memory).

One way to fix this is to use a method that guarantees construction before use, such as:

```
   static std::auto_ptr< singleton >& get_ptr() {
     static std::auto_ptr< singleton > ptr_(0);
     return ptr_;
   }
```

and replace references to `ptr_` with `get_ptr()`.

Answer (score 3):

The order of construction of file-scope objects defined in different translation units is unspecified. However, typically, objects defined in a translation unit that is linked before another translation unit are constructed before objects defined in the second translation unit. The difference here is the order in which `a.o` and `singleton.o` are linked. When `singleton.o` is linked before `a.o`, `singleton::ptr_` gets initialized before `dummy` and all is well. When `a.o` is linked first, `dummy` gets initialized first, which constructs the singleton; then `singleton::ptr_` gets initialized to 0, throwing away the pointer to the original copy of `singleton`.  Then in the call to `foo`, the call to `singleton::get()` constructs the singleton again.