# static property which returns class instance

Tags: c#, properties, static

I would like to use something similar as [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference)! Part of the source code looks like that:

```
public struct Vector3
{
    public static Vector3 zero { get; }
}
```

This function returns an already initialized Vector (which 0 on every axis). Is this possible, because it is a struct? That's what I have:

```
public class WorldBlock
{
    public enum e_WorldBlockType
    {
        Undef,
        Earth,
        Stone,
        Air // no block set
    }

    public static WorldBlock Empty { get; }
    public e_WorldBlockType BlockType { get; set; }
    public bool IsWalkable { get; set; }

    public WorldBlock(e_WorldBlockType blockType = e_WorldBlockType.Undef, bool isWalkable = false)
    {
        this.BlockType = blockType;
        this.IsWalkable = isWalkable;
    }
}
```

But I get this: `error CS0840: 'WorldBlock.Empty.get' must have a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. The property can be automatically implemented when you define both accessors`

How should I write the body?

EDIT:
If I add for example a `private set`, it compiles, but if I use it, I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singleton: How should it be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How many people will re-invent their own, buggy `Lazy<T>`, when answering this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private static WorldBlock __empty = ...;

public static WorldBlock Empty {
  get {
    return WorldBlock __empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, that might be the solution, give me a sec

Comment: Can smbd tell me, if this holds just one instance of an empty WorldBlock, so if I had 20 instances of WorldBlock, there is just one `__empty` instance?

Comment: @immerhart: `WorldBlock.Empty == new WorldBlock()` will evaluate to `false`. Is this normal behavior for you?

Comment: Don't know why... What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want an empty WorldBlock I suggest you write:

```
public static readonly WorldBlock Empty = new WorldBlock();
```

Instead of your Property. However it's kind of dodgy since the setters of the "Empty" object is public, so there's really no guarantee that it's actually empty.

Comment: +1. Since `WorldBlock` is mutable, there's no much sense in `WorldBlock.Empty`. Also, you have a typo - field name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
public static WorldBlock Empty
{
  get{return someThing; }
}
```

Replace `someThing` with whatever you were wanting `Empty` to store.... If thats `null` or whatever.

From your title... it looks like you want to return an instance of the class. If you only ever want one instance of this class... you're looking for the `Singleton` design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Should your "Empty" instances be shared and be the same? If so, the following body is probably what you are looking for.

```
private static WorldBlock emptyInstance;
public static WorldBlock Empty
{
   get
   {
      if (emptyInstance == null)
      {
         //initialize it
      }
      return emptyInstance;
   }
}
```