# Singleton with the strategy pattern

Tags: java, singleton, strategy-pattern

Here's what the interface of a strategy could look like

```
public interface Strategy
{
    public void doStuff(Object o);
}
```

And here's a possible implementation

```
public class StrategyImpl implements Strategy
{
    @Override
    public void doStuff(Object o)
    {
        //Do things with o
    }
}
```

Now, I might have hundreds of objects using the implementation StrategyImpl. Should a new instance of StrategyImpl be created for all of those hundreds of objects or is there a better way?
I've read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used/92193#92193) that singletons should not be used to save memory, but it seems really unnecessary to create hundreds of identical instances. Maybe the best solution wouldn't be a singleton but something along the lines of it.

How should I go about creating strategies? Should I not bother myself with these types of issues?

Comment: This is what Dependency Injection is for. Use guice/Spring to handle injecting your one instance of `StrategyImpl` to all dependent objects.

Comment: Strategy interface implementations seem like a great use for immutable/stateless singletons. The frameworks mentioned by @spinlok use singletons a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually a new implementation should be better. Singleton is a lot based on implementation of the Strategy with conditions that there should be e.g. no private attribute. That would work well for smaller and simpler strategies, but I won't recommend relying on that. Some more information about why singletons are bad in general can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: I read the top answer from your link, and I have a few comments for others reading your answer later: 1. Singletons don't _have_ to be a global instance. The singleton could be owned by a factory and passed to new instances.
2. This makes no sense. Does every class with a constructor violates the single responsibility principle?
3. *Nonsense*. They simply provide an immutable instance of code that can be shared.
4. Their state should be immutable. You make it once, and that's it.

Comment: @mhvelplund 1) Singleton is a design (anti)pattern which is from definition one instance in system, no matter if called directly or via factory, so yes, it is one global instance. 2) There is a difference between being constructed and being responsible for construction - objects with constructor are not generally responsible for the construction as long as the constructor is not called from within them - which is the case for singleton (anti)pattern. Learn more about SOLID principles. No idea what 3 and 4 refers to.