# How can I fix the C2065 error in C ++ when declaring an object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've changed from java to C++ a while ago. As soon as I try to code some complicated functions, I fail.
I wanna make a variable that points to the instance of my class. But even I try to declare the instance, I get this error...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include <string>

Game instance; // that should be the Instance

class Game
{
    public: 

    Game()
    {
        instance = this; // here I got the error.
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact text of the error message. You can copy that easily from the Output tab in Visual Studio ( not the errors list).

Comment: This is not how you want to create a singleton. Study the Meyer’s Singleton (if you really want a singleton): http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking for assistance with an error message please include the actual error text into the post itself. It is also a good idea to mention which specific version of the compiler such as which version of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: *I've changed from java to C++ a while ago* -- In C++, `this` is a pointer, not an object.  That explains why you're having a lot of issues -- assuming C++ uses the same rules as Java.

Comment: Also please realize that `java` and `c++` are very different languages even though they share some syntax. If you think like you do in `java` you will not produce good code in `c++`

Comment: Java is not C++. You will do yourself a big favor if you completely forget everything you know about Java, when attempting to learn C++. Despite the similar syntax, objects and classes in C++ work in fundamentally different ways from how they work in Java, and similar things are often completely different. Continuously drawing analogies with Java will only create non-stop confusion, like this.

Comment: Sounds like you want a singleton object. Search for how to correctly implement singleton in C++.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, unlike Java, When you write:

```
Game instance; // that should be the Instance
```

you are creating an actual object of type `Game`. In Java this would be creating a handle variable and you would then need to use the `new` operator to actually create the `Game` object. That is not the way it works in C++.

In the source lines:

```
Game()
{
    instance = this; // here I got the error.
}
```

the variable `this` is actually a pointer to the current object. However `instance` is not a pointer variable, which would be defined by `Game *instance;` but rather is an actual `Game` object. Assigning a pointer value to something that is not a pointer is a compile error.

One modification to your source, which may or may not be what you actually want, is to do the following changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include <string>

Game *instance; // global that contains a pointer to a Game object, no object created.

class Game
{
    public: 

    Game()
    {
        instance = this; // we are creating an object of class Game now assign it to our global.
    }
}
```

However this doesn't really make sense in C++. The constructor may be called more than once for multiple `Game` objects.

Assuming that the header file Game.h contains the class definition, if you are wanting to just create a single instance of `Game` then the most straightforward would be to write it as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include <string>

Game instance; // the global Game object that is created as part of the application starting up.
```

However if you are wanting to create a single instance using the [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which will enforce that there is one and only one such object created, you will need to do additional work which will require a more involved knowledge of C++ and class construction.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is that ‘this’ is a pointer in c++, not a reference to an object as in Java, so you must dereference it to assign it to an object:

```
instance = *this;
```

Be wary though that this will copy your object. Although this is how you could do this, I’d like to say that it is discouraged to use global variables and singletons in general. I’d rather recommend you to use a static class. For a discussion about that look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used). In summary: don’t use a singleton if you don’t have to.

Comment: That may fix the error but the code does not make sense.

Comment: Solves a compiler issue, but not the ideological problem. And since the ideological problem is ignored, the asker is set up for many further problems.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Also the copy does not make a lot of sense because `Game instance;` already is an instance to an object with file scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should de declare instance as a pointer to Game:

```
Game *instance = NULL;
```

Comment: Personally I think this is a bad idea, but I'm willing to change my mind if you can update this answer with a good explanation of why this will help.

Comment: Now I get the Compiler-Error C2440 ""=": "Game *" can not be converted to "int *""

Comment: You shouldn’t use pointers if you don’t have to. The main reason is ownership. Should the memory pointed by the pointer be deallocated, if yes than who is supposed to deallocate it?

Comment: @SpruceCode that's probably an error resulting from another error and a legacy hold-over from the C programming language that still exists in some C++ compilers . when `Game *instance = NULL;` is found by the compiler, it doesn't know what `Game` is yet, so in C, it would assume `int`. Bad things follow from this. In C++, most things must be declared BEFORE you can use them. [A good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will cover what you can get away with.