# how to interpret the static code in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, static, singleton

I just found some source codes, written in C++11. The code is like this:

```
inline Class& function() {
    static Class x;
    return x;
}
```

and then for using this function I faced:

```
function().app();
```

Is this function() implements the Singleton Pattern? How it is working? It seems strange to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: [This may also be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/332733)

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine-static means on the stack, and return & means return a pointer to that, all very singular but no guarantee there is no Class x elsewhere in the process.  Wiki says you must hide the constructor, have a class method to return a reference to a class-static object: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern