# Are reference assignment and reading atomic operations?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have found several questions about this same topic but related to general variables (value and reference types)
The accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666/is-accessing-a-variable-in-c-an-atomic-operation) says:

Partition I, Section 12.6.6 of the CLI spec states: "A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size is atomic when all the write accesses to a location are the same size."

Reference variables (i.e. classes) are pointers, equal to the native word size, but I have a couple doubts:

Are references guaranteed to be in properly aligned memory locations?

I don't understand the last part. What does this mean? *"...when all the write accesses to a location are the same size."*

In short, is obj2 guaranteed to be valid in every iteration of the loop in the following code?

```
class MyClass
{
    private OtherClass m_Object;

    void Thread1()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            OtherClass obj1 = new OtherClass();
            m_Object = obj1;
        }
    }

    void Thread2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            OtherClass obj2 = m_Object;
            // Is obj2 guaranteed to be valid?
            obj2.Check();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, everything is guaranteed to be properly aligned unless you deliberately go out of your way to misalign stuff, meaning that reference assignment/reading is guaranteed to be atomic.

Section 12.6.6 of the CLI spec goes on to say this:

> Unless explicit layout control (see
>   Partition II (Controlling Instance
>   Layout)) is used to alter the default
>   behavior, data elements no larger than
>   the natural word size (the size of a
>   `native int`) shall be properly
>   aligned. Object references shall be
>   treated as though they are stored in
>   the native word size.

There are also further details about alignment etc in section 12.6.2 of the spec.

Note that in your example code, the read in thread 2 is guaranteed to be atomic, but it's *not* guaranteed to actually see any changes made by thread 1: without enforcing memory barriers or volatility each thread can use its own "view" of the `m_Object` field without ever seeing changes made by other threads.

So, for example, thread 1 could be making (atomic) writes into its own view of `m_Object`, but the data is only ever actually held in a register or CPU cache and never comitted to main memory. Similarly, thread 2 could also be making (atomic) reads of `m_Object`, but actually reading from a register or CPU cache rather than main memory.

Comment: that's pretty interesting, thank you. What if inside the loops, instead of the direct read/assignment of the m_Object variable, there were calls to methods that actually did the read/assignment? Would the volatility problem still exist?

Comment: @Jaime: Yes, unless there's some sort of forced synchronisation -- volatile field, memory barrier, lock, `Interlocked` call etc -- then it can still happen. (In my experience this sort of thing doesn't bite very often but it *does* occasionally, so better to avoid it altogether.)