# How to implement Switch for IObservable<IObserver<T>> for reactive extensions in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In reactive extensions we have

```
IObservable<T> Switch(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> This)
```

I would like an implementation of

```
IObserver<T> Switch(this IObservable<IObserver<T>> This)
```

which would switch the outgoing events to different observers but 
presented as a single observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version handles a couple of issues:

- There's a race condition that can result in lost events.  If the observer observes an event on one thread while the source observable produces a new observer on another thread, if you do not use any sort of synchronization, you could end up calling `OnCompleted` on the current observer on one thread just before the other thread calls `OnNext` on that same observer.  This will result in the event being lost.
- Related to the above, by default, observers are not thread-safe.  You should never concurrent calls to an observer or you will violate a primary Rx contract.  Without any locking, the subscriber might call `OnCompleted` on the `currentObserver` while another thread is calling `OnNext` on that same observer.  Out of the box, this sort of thing can be solved by using a Synchronized Subject.  But since we need synchronization also for the previous problem, we can just use a simple mutex.
- We need a way to unsubscribe from the source observable.  I'm supposing that when the resulting observer is completed (or errored), this is a good time to unsubscribe from source since our observer has been told to expect no more events.

Here's the code:

```
public static IObserver<T> Switch<T>(this IObservable<IObserver<T>> source)
{
    var mutex = new object();
    var current = Observer.Create<T>(x => {});
    var subscription = source.Subscribe(o =>
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
           current.OnCompleted();
           current = o;
        }
    });

    return Observer.Create<T>(
        onNext: v =>
        {
            lock(mutex)
            {                
              current.OnNext(v);
            }
        },
        onCompleted: () =>
        {
             subscription.Dispose();
             lock (mutex)
             {
                 current.OnCompleted();
             }
        },
        onError: e =>
        {
             subscription.Dispose();
             lock (mutex)
             {
                 current.OnError(e);
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you really think Interlocked.CompareExchange is required? What race condition are you protecting from. Reference copy is atomic in .net. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816939/are-reference-assignment-and-reading-atomic-operations

Comment: However disposing of the subscription looks to be required as you have added in.

Comment: Actually I just realized CompareExchange is not enough.  There are 2 race conditions: One is that your observer is likely observing events on a different thread than your observable is producing new observers.  Without some sort of protection, when your observer observes an event, it might grab the old `currentObserver` just as it changed and send the event to the wrong observer.  The other issue is it might send the event *after* you've completed the observer which means that event will get lost.  I'll update my answer to use an actual lock.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IObserver<T> Switch<T>(this IObservable<IObserver<T>> This)
{
    IObserver<T> currentObserver = Observer.Create<T>(x => { });

    This.Subscribe(o => { currentObserver.OnCompleted(); currentObserver = o; });


    return Observer.Create<T>
        ( onNext: v => currentObserver.OnNext(v)
        , onCompleted: () => currentObserver.OnCompleted()
        , onError: v => currentObserver.OnError(v));
}
```

Comment: you are dropping out all previous observers. is it ok?

Comment: I call OnCompleted as I drop out the previous. It is the intention to drop out the previous observers.

Comment: in you question it sounds like "switch the outgoing events to different observers" not (for example) "switch the outgoing events to the last observer". it is confusing a bit (at least for me)

Comment: It should be the dual of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229197%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: This solution has race conditions around `currentObserver`.  And it "leaks" the subscription to `This`.  There doesn't seem to be a way to ever unsubscribe.  Should `This` be unsubscribed if the observer sees a complete or error event?

Comment: Reference assignment in .net is atomic but the subscription to This is problematic maybe.