# Are locks needed if access order is unimportant for atomic type variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Say I have a variable that will be accessed by 2 different threads.

Only thread A will ever be writing to this variable.

Thread B will be checking on this variable in a loop and performing actions based on what is stored there.

I don't particularly care when these actions are performed because they can be grabbed on the next iteration, or even skipped altogether. As long as the variable is something atomic (bool, int, reference to an object...), do I need a lock here? Is there any chance of B grabbing something unexpected?

Comment: you should mark it as [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/x13ttww7.aspx)

Comment: @heinzbeinz I was under the impression that was just some sort of hint to the compiler for optimization purposes. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: It depends on the variable. 32bit size variables are atomic, but long/double are not. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666/is-accessing-a-variable-in-c-sharp-an-atomic-operation

Comment: According to MSDN, volatile simply ensures that the most up-to-date value is always present in the variable by preventing certain compiler optimizations. Since I only care that the value is mosly-up-to-date and will eventually be actually-up-to-date, I'm now wondering if even 'volatile' is needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Comment: As far as I know it is dangerous to read non volatile 64bit variables without a lock as you could read it while it is half written which would lead to invalid values. Just to be safe I would mark it as volatile.

Comment: @Camander - without `volatile`, `B` may never actually re-read the memory location. So it will continue to see the first value it ever observed.

Comment: See **Loop Read Hoisting** in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/jj883956.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Well that's a little scary. Volatile it is then. So using a lock is unnecessary in this case?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the article! I didn't know about the loop read hoisting. So volatile is needed even in the 32bit case.